# Textfield for autocomplete material ui

Tags: autocomplete, material-ui

How can we clear the text field for a autocomplete component automatically after a button click.
I want to clear the textfield after every button click for a autocomplete ui component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I understood your question correctly.
I forked the controlled example in documentation and changed a little bit for the question.

Button clears the TextField. Here is [my demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/playground-material-demo-forked-ugn0s?file=/demo.js)

Comment: thank you  this is exactly what I am looking for and it worked as well